# How to get default blue colour of matplotlib.pyplot.scatter?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I get the shade of blue that is used as default in `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`? When giving the keyword argument `c='b'`, it gives a darker shade of blue. In this [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) of `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`, it says the default is supposed to be `'b'`, yet it looks different.

See example below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(-1, 0)
ax.text(-1, 0, 'Default blue')
ax.scatter(1, 0, c='b')
ax.text(1, 0, 'Darker blue')
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
```

[image: Figure]

I'm using Python 3.5 with Matplotlib 2.0.0. The reason why I'm asking this, is because I would like to use the same blue colour when plotting some of the points one by one with `plt.plot()`.

Comment: The default colour cycle was changed in matplotlib 2. See [this](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colors-color-cycles-and-color-maps) part of the docs

Comment: this worked for me `MY_DEFAULT_BLUE: str = '#1f77b4'` e.g. `axs.plot(x, y, marker='x', label=label, lw=linewidth, color='#1f77b4')`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The default colour cycle was changed in matplotlib version 2 as shown in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colors-color-cycles-and-color-maps).

Therefore, to plot the "new" default blue you can do 2 things:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(-1, 1)
ax.text(-0.9, 1, 'Default blue')

ax.scatter(1, 1, c='#1f77b4')
ax.text(1.1, 1, 'Using hex value')

ax.scatter(0, 0.5, c='C0')
ax.text(0.1, 0.5, 'Using "C0" notation')

ax.set_xlim(-2, 3)
ax.set_ylim(-1,2)
plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Alternatively you can change the colour cycle back to what it was:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from cycler import cycler

mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = cycler(color='bgrcmyk')
```

Comment: Just to add on that, `'C0'` is equivalent to `'tab:blue'`, if you'd like a more meaningful string value (https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colors.html)

Answer (score 11):

As noted in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colors.html), the default color cycle is the "Tableau Colors". These can be accessed using `'tab:blue'`, `'tab:orange'`, `'tab:green'`, etc.

So applied to your example, it would be

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(-1, 0)
ax.text(-1, 0, 'Default blue')
ax.scatter(1, 0, c='tab:blue')
ax.text(1, 0, 'Also default blue')
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
```

(Credit to @Tulio Casagrande's comment)